# Excel Pasting Values into a Table - Different Outcomes on Different Machines

Tags: vba, excel, paste

I've have a bit of an issue with Excel. The VBA code works perfectly on my computer. It takes non continuous data and pastes it into a table and Excel automatically inserts the rows and the formulas.

However on my colleagues computer, only the first piece of data goes into the table and the rest goes into the cells below the table. It hasn't inserted the rows and therefore the formulas haven't come down either.

Is there some settings I need to enable/disable on their computers to get this to work?

Comment: Can you kindly post the code?

Comment: Sheets("SITS Requests").Select
    Range("A5", Range("A5").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("Refund Data").Select
    Range("A7").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Comment: Could this be a code issue though? If it works perfectly on my computer but has a completely different outcome on my colleagues?

Answer (score 0):

I can´t see a problem with you code, but I still have some advice for you:

You shouldn´t use `.Select` and `Selection.` if you can avoid it.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("SITS Requests").Range("A5", Sheets("SITS Requests").Range("A5").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cop‌​y
Sheets("Refund Data").Range("A7").Paste
```